# How to get the sales and collection amount values from a query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Hello everyone please have a look at the query below and see what the problem is with the Oracle query.i have used two tables named **Bill_mas** and **Remit_bill**.would appreciate the help very much.

Query :

```
SELECT x.sc_cd, x.rm_id, x.fm_id, x.bill_no, x.DELI_DT, X.SALE_NET, Y.RMT, Y.COLL
FROM
(
    SELECT sc_cd, rm_id, fm_id, bill_no, DELI_DT, SUM(sale_net) SALE_NET
    FROM BILL_MAS 
    WHERE DELI_DT BETWEEN '01-feb-15' and '28-feb-15'
    AND BILL_NO = '754105'
    AND sc_cd = '09'
    AND SALE_CD NOT IN ('RS','IN','EX')
    HAVING ROUND(SUM(SALE_NET),2) <= 1000
    GROUP BY sc_cd, rm_id, fm_id, bill_no, DELI_DT
) X,
(
    SELECT p.sc_cd, MAX(RMT_DT) RMT, SUM(p.COLL_AMT) COLL
    FROM REMIT_BILL P
    WHERE p.bill_no = '754105' 
    AND p.rmt_DT =
    (
        SELECT MAX(rmt_DT) FROM REMIT_BILL P2
        WHERE P2.bill_no = P.BILL_NO
        AND sc_cd = '09'
    )
    GROUP BY p.sc_cd, p.RMT_DT,p.COLL_AMT
) Y
WHERE X.bill_no = y.bill_no
AND X.sc_cd = y.sc_cd
ORDER BY 1
```

Error message :

```
WHERE X.bill_no=y.bill_no
                *
ERROR at line 18:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_Y'
```

Tables :

```
SQL> 
SQL> desc bill_mas
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 BILL_NO                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
 BILL_DT                         NOT NULL DATE
 ORDER_NO                                 VARCHAR2(6)
 ORDER_DT                                 DATE
 FP_ID                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
 SC_CD                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 DIST_CD                                  VARCHAR2(2)
 THA_CD                                   VARCHAR2(2)
 UN_CD                                    VARCHAR2(3)
 CL_ID                                    VARCHAR2(3)
 SALE_CD                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 SALE_GR                         NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)
 SALE_NET                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)
 DELI_DT                                  DATE
 FL_MVH                                   VARCHAR2(1)
 USER_CD                                  VARCHAR2(2)
 W_DT                                     DATE
 CANCL                                    VARCHAR2(1)
 B_VAT                                    NUMBER(9,2)
 RM_ID                                    VARCHAR2(5)
 FM_ID                                    VARCHAR2(5)
 BS_CD                                    VARCHAR2(4)
 C_TYP                                    VARCHAR2(1)
 COLL_TYP                                 VARCHAR2(1)

SQL> desc remit_bill
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 SC_CD                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 RMT_NO                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
 RMT_DT                                   DATE
 BILL_NO                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
 COLL_AMT                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)

SQL>
```

Query with the date column **p.rmt_dt** :

```
SELECT t1.bill_no, t2.sc_cd, t2.RMT, t2.COLL
    FROM REMIT_BILL t1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT p.sc_cd sc_cd, MAX(RMT_DT) RMT, SUM(p.COLL_AMT) COLL
        FROM REMIT_BILL P
        --WHERE p.bill_no = '754105' 
        WHERE p.rmt_DT =
        (
            SELECT MAX(rmt_DT) FROM REMIT_BILL P2
            WHERE P2.bill_no = P.BILL_NO 
            AND sc_cd = '09' 
            AND P.RMT_DT BETWEEN '01-FEB-15' AND '28-FEB-15'
        )
        GROUP BY p.sc_cd, p.RMT_DT,p.COLL_AMT
    ) t2
    ON t1.sc_cd = t2.sc_cd AND t1.rmt_dt = t2.rmt
```

Comment: What are the all the primary and foreign keys in each of the tables?

Comment: There is no such reference to y.bill_no in your query.

Comment: @Iftekhar In general you should not change your question after you have posted it, because it can invalidate all the answers (and work) already done.

Comment: ok Tim i will ask a new question with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outermost `WHERE` clause is referencing a column `bill_no` in the inner query `Y`, but this inner query never selected that column, so I suspect it won't be available.  To make the `bill_no` column available, you can `JOIN` the `remit_bill` table back onto itself in the `Y` query and then carry on as you were.  Try changing your query to this:

```
SELECT x.sc_cd, x.rm_id, x.fm_id, x.bill_no, x.DELI_DT, X.SALE_NET, Y.RMT, Y.COLL
FROM
(
    SELECT sc_cd, rm_id, fm_id, bill_no, DELI_DT, SUM(sale_net) SALE_NET
    FROM BILL_MAS 
    WHERE DELI_DT BETWEEN '01-feb-15' and '28-feb-15'
    AND BILL_NO = '754105'
    AND sc_cd = '09'
    AND SALE_CD NOT IN ('RS','IN','EX')
    HAVING ROUND(SUM(SALE_NET),2) <= 1000
    GROUP BY sc_cd, rm_id, fm_id, bill_no, DELI_DT
) X,
(
    SELECT t1.bill_no, t2.sc_cd, t2.RMT, t2.COLL
    FROM REMIT_BILL t1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT p.sc_cd sc_cd, MAX(RMT_DT) RMT, SUM(p.COLL_AMT) COLL
        FROM REMIT_BILL P
        WHERE p.bill_no = '754105' 
        AND p.rmt_DT =
        (
            SELECT MAX(rmt_DT) FROM REMIT_BILL P2
            WHERE P2.bill_no = P.BILL_NO
            AND sc_cd = '09'
        )
        GROUP BY p.sc_cd, p.RMT_DT,p.COLL_AMT
    ) t2
    ON t1.sc_cd = t2.sc_cd AND t1.rmt_dt = t2.rmt
    WHERE t1.bill_no = '754105'
) Y
WHERE X.bill_no = y.bill_no
AND X.sc_cd = y.sc_cd
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.i executed your query but no luck.same error persists.

Comment: WHERE X.bill_no = y.bill_no
                  *
ERROR at line 31:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_Y'

Comment: it worked now after you edited the query.thanks Tim.let me see if i can properly comprehend the whole query.cheers.